Audio not working when trying to export a Twine game to Android/IOS with Monaca?
I'm making a twine game with background music and I would like to export it to an Android and IOS app. Since my programming skills are very basic, I decided to use Monaca because it seems like it's the simplest option, and while it works perfectly, for some reason the audio doesn't. It should be easy, just upload the index file, images and music to the "www" folder. The project works as intended, the images display when they should, but there's no audio and I don't know why. What could the problem be? The songs are all mp3 files, and they are in different folders (effects in one, and songs in other) inside one main folder which is named "audio", in case this helps find the solution.
I've tried using a different browser, moving the audio folder to "res" and named it "raw", I also tried to upload the music manually, but none of those worked. It should go in the "www" folder, but I have no idea why it's not working.
